# Prevent jQuery from changing background-color

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jQuery to change `background-color` of even rows of a table:

```
$("table tbody tr:nth-child(even)").css("background-color", "#F1F1F1");
```

Now I want to set another color to one of my `tr`s according to result of some PHP tasks.

```
<tr
    <?php
        // Some tasks to see whether background-color should change or not
        if (yes) echo "style='background-color:#A60000;'"
    ?>
>
```

But it doesn't work since jQuery overrides the color and set it back to `#F1F1F1`. Is there any way to prevent jQuery from doing this? Or I should use jQuery as well?

Comment: Have you considered a CSS class?

Comment: You should really be doing this with `classes`, which will give you a lot more control (`!important`) etc. `$("table tbody tr:nth-child(even)").addClass('even')`.

Comment: What is the sequence of events here? Are you running the jQuery code on the current page and then reloading the page to get new rows?

Comment: No. Actually the page populates with html rendered by php and then jQuery do some tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `$.css` to add the color, but use `addClass` instead to add a class to the row. In PHP, also add a class instead of an inline style.

Then, in your style sheet, you can style the rows accordingly:

```
/* The class that is added by JQuery */
.jqueryclass {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

/* The class that is added by PHP, even if jquery added a class too. */
.phpclass, .phpclass.jqueryclass {
  background-color: #A60000;
}
```

It is much cleaner and more maintanable. You can let the CSS decide how specific combinations of classes are styled, without having to do complex and confusing checks in javascript or PHP.

And if you do have a CSS file at this point, you can add CSS classes to style the alternate rows. That way, it works on browsers that have javascript disabled. In time, you can get rid of the JQuery code alltogether, when browsers that don't support this style have become extinct.

Answer (score 1):

Just add something like

```
data-nooverride
```

just after/before style attribute.

(You'll have to edit following code to use each):

```
var tr = $("table tbody tr:nth-child(even)");
if (tr.data('nooverride')){
    $("table tbody tr:nth-child(even)").css("background-color", "#F1F1F1");
}
```

and check it with your script

Comment: `tr` will be multiple, so you'd have to `each` over the `tr`'s and check the data attribute for each.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. You'll need to identify the row somehow (probably by adding a class),

```
<tr
    <?php
        if (yes) echo "class='myclass' style='background-color:#A60000;'"
    ?>
>
```

And then modify the jQuery selector to ignore that row

```
$(selector).not('.myclass').css({...});
```

Since you're adding a class, you should probably put the background color as part of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding a `style` attribute to the `tr` tag, add a `class` from your PHP code.

Then, just change your jQuery selector to not modify `tr` tags that have the given class, as in below (see the [jQuery documentation on :not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)). The class, in this case, is called `special`:

```
$("table tbody tr:nth-child(even):not(.special)").css("background-color", "#F1F1F1");
```

See this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/UfvAR/).

Comment: Even better: Use classes altogethers. Why pollute the Javascript/JQuery logic with hard coded style values. That's what your style sheets are for.

Comment: True, classes > inline styles.

Answer (score -1):

In css if you add "!important" after some styling, it tells the browser that this style has the highest priority.

So you can make a class for it and in your css file:

```
.myclass{
  background-color:#A60000 !important;
}
```

You can try to add it in the style attribute, but i am not sure though if it will work this way